# Modify the compliance level of a jar file

Tags: java, javac

In my application I include a jar which is compile with JDK 1.7. On the system I test my application I only have JDK 1.6. When I run the application I get this error:

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

In order to eliminate this error I want to obtain a jar compiled with JDK 1.6 from the initial jar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools for doing this sort of thing.  I don't know how successful they are. Or whether they support Java 6.  Most seem aimed at Java 5.0 to Java 1.4

http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/

http://www.glazedlists.com/Home/declawer

http://www.jboss.org/jbossretro